# Specific days for datepicker with json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a booking form with specific days and I colored my specific days if you click on my datepicker you will see

so my quesiton is I use array list for my specific

```js
var firstDate = ['2017-06-15'];
var lastDate = ['2017-12-20'];
var availabledays = ['2017-06-15', '2017-06-16', '2017-06-23', '2017-06-30', ];
var booked = ['2017-06-16', '2017-06-23', '2017-06-24', '2017-06-25'];
var ssdays = [];
```

but I have to use json that's why I created a json file as below

dates.json

```js
{
    "firstDate": [
        { "field": "2017-06-15"}
    ],
    "lasDate":[
        {"field":"2017-12-20"}
    ],
    
    "availabledays":[
        {"field":"2017-06-15"},
        {"field":"2017-06-16"},
        {"field":"2017-06-23"},
        {"field":"2017-06-30"}
    ],
    "booked":[
        {"field":"2017-06-16"},
        {"field":"2017-06-23"},
        {"field":"2017-06-24"},
        {"field":"2017-06-25"}
    ]
}
```

and my question is how to request from server mys json files and then put into datepicker when focus?

and this is my datepicker example full demo

```js
$(function() {
    var firstDate  = ['2017-06-15'];
    var lastDate  = ['2017-12-20'];
    var availabledays  = ['2017-06-15','2017-06-16','2017-06-23','2017-06-30',];
    var booked = ['2017-06-16','2017-06-23','2017-06-24','2017-06-25'];
    var ssdays   = [];
  
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    from = $("#checkin").datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        firstDay:1,
        minDate:new Date(firstDate),
        maxDate:new Date(lastDate),
       onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        var newdate = new Date();

        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
          date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000*60*60*24))
         
            $( "#checkout" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate",date  );
           },
      
        beforeShowDay : function(date){
          var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
          var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
          var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
          if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
          if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
          var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
          if(jQuery.inArray(currDate,availabledays) >= 0){
            return [false, "ui-highlight"]; 
          } 
        
          if(jQuery.inArray(currDate,booked) >= 0){
            return [true, "ui-bos"];  
          }else{
            return [true];
          }             
        
        },
      isTo1: true,
    }).on("change", function() {
      to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
    }),
    to = $("#checkout").datepicker({
      changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        firstDay:1,
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        minDate:new Date(firstDate),
        maxDate:new Date(lastDate),
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#checkin" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
           },
        beforeShowDay : function(date){
          var y = date.getFullYear().toString(); // get full year
          var m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(); // get month.
          var d = date.getDate().toString(); // get Day
          if(m.length == 1){ m = '0' + m; } // append zero(0) if single digit
          if(d.length == 1){ d = '0' + d; } // append zero(0) if single digit
          var currDate = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
          
          if(jQuery.inArray(currDate,booked) >= 0){
            return [true, "ui-highlight-donus"];  
          } 
          if(jQuery.inArray(currDate,availabledays) >= 0){
            return [true, "ui-bos"];  
          }
          if(jQuery.inArray(currDate,ssdays) >= 0){
            return [true, "ui-ss-donus"]; 
          }else{
            return [true];
          }  
        }
    }).on("change", function() {
      from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
    });

});
```

```css
.form{
  width:960px;
  margin:120px auto;
}
.form input{
  width:250px;
  padding:10px;
}
.ui-highlight .ui-state-default{background: red !important;border-color: red !important;color: white !important; cursor:no-drop;}
  .ui-bos .ui-state-default{background: green !important;border-color: green !important;color: white !important;}
  .ui-ss .ui-state-default{background: yellow !important;border-color: yellow !important;color: gray !important; cursor:help;}
  .ui-ss-donus .ui-state-default{background: yellow !important;border-color: yellow !important;color: gray !important; cursor:help;} 
  .ui-highlight-donus .ui-state-default{background: red !important;border-color: red !important;color: white !important; } 
.ui-testtarih .ui-state-default{
  background:black !important;
  color:#FFF !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">

<div class="form">
  <input type="text" id="checkin" />
  <input type="text" id="checkout" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this is about the third time you've asked this but it's not at all clear where your specific problem is in making request for the data. As I have suggested previously...make the request, then initialize datepicker in ajax success

Comment: yes I have been looking for a answer because I have more experience with jquery and ajax so I need help sorry

Comment: there is no issue about specific my question is I want to use json for my specific array that's all

Comment: OK... very little would change. Make ajax request ...then initialize datepicker with that data instead once it is received

Comment: I guess I couldn't  tell :) I have no any ajax experience that's why I couldn't do it

Comment: could you give any example ?

Comment: Not much more complicated than `$.getJSON(url, function(data){ /* same code as you already have with minor change in variables */})`

Comment: but my question is about to apply I look json example and I see your example and it work I can get json data but I couldn't apply to my datepicker..that's why I need example.

Comment: you said not much more complicated than ? so could you give a example ?

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle or plunker with your working code and will transform with ajax

Comment: Ok I will create now

Comment: here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/qtqoyh5s/1/

Comment: Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/6i6MYcgMhVONPU0s1TKr?p=preview

Comment: thank you so much I could not do it if it was left to me.I want to check your answer thank yo so so much you saved my life!

Comment: If data in json file was same array structure of strings not objects as original arrays in variables you wouldn't need the extra `flattenFieldsArray()` function

Answer (score 1):

I would disable the datepicker and grey them out while the request is happening and enable them after the request completed. The jquery ui datepicker can be disabled with `$('#checkout').datepicker('disable')`.

As far as the data format, you can write a couple functions to pull that data out in a success callback.  Something like

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your-data-url.com"
})
  .done(function(serverFormattedDays) {
    var availableDays = serverFormattedDays.map(function(day) {
      return day.field;
    }
    // code to create/edit/modify datepickers here.
};
```

will return the available days in the format you want.

Comment: I learnt how to get json data using jquery but I couldn't apply for my datepicker so thanks can we apply to datepicker ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'apply for my datepicker'.  When I checked it, the code you had was working properly.  You just needed to defer enabling/showing them until the data has been fetched.